# how to hide dropdownlist1 selected values in dropdownlist2 dynamically in ASP.Net Mvc3Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Iam using ASP.Net MVC3 Razor, I have two dropdowns in .cshtml, let's say ddl1 and ddl2.
I have binded data in the controller and sent to dropdowns using viewbag.
Both the ddls have same data in it like A,B,C,D. If I select A in ddl1, it should hide A in ddl2; if select B it should hide B in ddl2.  Could any one help me out using javascript or jquery.

This is my controller where I have binded..

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ddl1 = new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.ddl2 = new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

and the View is(.cshtml for the above action)

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>      
       @Html.DropDownList("ddl1", "-select name-")
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("ddl2","-select name-")
          </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1):

here is the main idea. Let's say we have 2 dropdown lists:

```
<select id="ddl1">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<select id="ddl2">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
</select>​
```

to remove the ddl1 selected value from ddl2:

```
$('#ddl1').change(function() {
    $('#ddl2 option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == $('#ddl1 option:selected').attr('value')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Also to remove the ddl2 selected value from ddl1:

```
$('#ddl2').change(function() {
    $('#ddl1 option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == $('#ddl2 option:selected').attr('value')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to reload the dropdown values back on every change, simply call your dropdown populating function again. I hope this will help...

Also here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cJ8wN/8/

Comment: This code is working well, and I need one more help.. When i go back and select the other options of ddl1, then ddl2 must be refreshed..  could you help me out

Comment: once you go back, if you call your drop down list populating function again, it will be refreshed.